# Using JavaScript to create arrays from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to explain the best I can what I am trying to archive though the medium of MS Paint.

[image]

I have an exported list of bookmarks from Chrome.

I want to be able to ingest this into a web app I am making to strip out certain info thats relevant to me, build a GUI folder structure from HTML/CSS/JS and then list the URLs/Descriptions for all my bookmarks.

The end goal being a web app I can use that utilizes webviews/iframes to show my bookmarked pages all from in one app.

**How far I have got**

A -> B

```
var map = { };

$('Break').children().each(function(_, node) {
    map[ _ ] = { };
    map[ _ ][ node.nodeName ] = node.textContent;
});
```

This strips out all the info I need. Its the next part I am struggling with. Is it possible using JavaScript to turn (B) into a bunch of arrays that I can then call using some variables to list my pages how I want?

From there I am comfortable with the rest.

Example BookMarks (Input)

```
<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495544136" LAST_MODIFIED="1495544331">Test Folder 1 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495544331" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546321">Test 1 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546129" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546445">Test 1 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495546321" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495546340" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495546445" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546969" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546987">Test Folder 2 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546987" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547012">Test 2 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547012" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547167">Test 2 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547034" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547056">Test Folder 3 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547056" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547084">Test 3 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547084" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547171">Test 3 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
    </DL><p>
</DL><p>
```

Using method A -> B (output)

```
Test Folder 1 (Tier 1)
Test 1 (Tier 2)
Test 1 (Tier 3)
Stack Overflow
DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code
Home - BBC News
Test Folder 2 (Tier 1)
Test 2 (Tier 2)
Test 2 (Tier 3)
Stack Overflow
DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code
Home - BBC News
Test Folder 3 (Tier 1)
Test 3 (Tier 2)
Test 3 (Tier 3)
Stack Overflow
DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code
Home - BBC News
```

Comment: Is (B) where you are at now? You don't have any URL's within that output. Is the folder structure consistent? (i.e. currently, every example just has 3 'Test ...' nodes above it)

Comment: B is where I am now. sorry the output shown was from an earlier test, I now have it showing URLs (See top pic) Yes the folder structure is consistent. Only ever 3 Tiers: Root, Sub Folder 1, Sub folder 2 (Containing urls, descriptions) There will only ever be 6 root folders though

Comment: I think it may be easier just to skip the 'B' stage and just transform directly from the HTML source into the array you are after. By condensing down to the 'B' output, you are actually losing some data structure that is useful to use in generating the array you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the most efficient solution, and might need some further tweaking, but the following code snippet will parse the HTML and produce an array of objects with the following schema.

```
{
    root: // Root dir
    sub1: // Subdir 1
    sub2: // Subdir 2
    urls: [
        { url: 'example.com', description: 'Example' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

```js
var nodes = $.makeArray($('.content').children())
var arr = nodes.map(node => {
 node = $(node)
 const root = node.find('h3')[0].textContent
 const sub1 = node.find('dt > h3')[0].textContent
 const sub2 = node.find('dt dt > h3')[0].textContent
 const urls = $.makeArray(node.find('dt dt dt > a')).map(n => {
  n = $(n)
  return {
   url: n.attr('href'),
   description: n[0].innerText
  }
 })
 
 return {
  root: root,
  sub1: sub1,
  sub2: sub2,
  urls: urls
 }
})

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495544136" LAST_MODIFIED="1495544331">Test Folder 1 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495544331" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546321">Test 1 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546129" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546445">Test 1 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495546321" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495546340" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495546445" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546969" LAST_MODIFIED="1495546987">Test Folder 2 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495546987" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547012">Test 2 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547012" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547167">Test 2 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAACC0lEQVQ4jc2SO4gTYRSFz//feWWSaHQnM2GHTZNNlS67bGFlvYXaLWhnp5WNnZ2dnaxopZVgZWElbGO/6EAkJIWGQBhI3BnMY9U89n/YZCGKBGzEAwducc6Fy/2AfyT+N2G29J9Ev8+0JgwADgCxu7u7FwTBYjAYfFt29NJgAEwAZwBQq9UuM8YCItpoNBrHtVrNYoxdchznaLFY3BBCyFar9XnlLEUAlOd5+a2tLa/dbo/CMLzPOb/S7/ffJEkyD8PwJmPMVkp9NAxjr1gs5kulkmPbtjRN0+QATM/zNizLqtbr9UeMsarW+jEAtbm56QI4mM/nTwzDKBiGcZuI9pVSwnVdnqbplJfL5RwRzSzLeqm1nkZRdD2O4w4AXSqVDojIbjabx1EUHU0mk2tElLMs63A2m0kAnPd6vWGapqda64ec8+2dnZ27vu8DAOOc35FSPgOggiDIZLPZUGt9UWv9XWudKRQKLhWLxZzrunkiOmGMCSLaJyLm+77POb8aRdE9AKpard4iogdSyhcAXnHOEcfxFyNJkkU2mx0JIc6klO+klLHW+oPjOK+VUs8BKAAmY6wuhDhsNBpvK5XKhU6nkwBgBECORiOZpumPNE2/5nK5k+l0qmzb3h6Px0+Hw6ECgEwm8940zU+u64put3u65MBcpe8crFXaAMBa/nwdcL+wfr5gbeH/0U9As88ACmZhwgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495547167" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547034" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547056">Test Folder 3 (Tier 1)</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547056" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547084">Test 3 (Tier 2)</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1495547084" LAST_MODIFIED="1495547171">Test 3 (Tier 3)</H3>
                <DL><p>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Stack Overflow</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="https://dirtymarkup.com/" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">DirtyMarkup · Tidy up your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code</A>
                    <DT><A HREF="http://www.bbc.com/news" ADD_DATE="1495547171" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAT0lEQVQ4je2RMQ7AIAwDz/z/z+5QgajJUmXlxkO2kQIXAe7kB4Bt7G9P5So/VpV0BNLZRhKSzoL5mGvpkl8/qNA75BXY19MVXu0rNLKXyQMkVzL9n5I6iQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">Home - BBC News</A>
                </DL><p>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
    </DL><p>
       </DL><p></div>
```

Comment: krob, thats great! really given me something to work with, much appreciate,